# How to use user location out of locationmanager function swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-location, distance, cllocationmanager

i am kinda new to coding and have come up with this problem. I im making af trashcanfinder app based on MapKit and I would like to show the distance from the user location to my pins on the map. I have already made my function to convert a CLLocationCoordinate2D to a CLLocation, and have a function to show distance from one point to another, but I can't seem to use the user location out of the locationmanager function.

This is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true


}



    func distancePointToPoint(location1: CLLocationCoordinate2D, location2: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> String {
        let cllocation1 = converter(location: location1)
        let cllocation2 = converter(location: location2)
        let distance = cllocation1.distance(from: cllocation2)
        let shortDistance = distance - distance.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 0.1)                                   //makes sure there is only one number behind comma
        if shortDistance < 0 {
            return "The distance is \(shortDistance) meters"
        }
        else {
            return "The distance is \(shortDistance - (shortDistance / 1000).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 0.1)) kilometers"
        }
    }
```

So I need to use the user location as location1 in the distancePointToPoint function.

I know that with any other function I could just return the value, but I don't have any values to give the locationmanager function as it will get it from the device itself.

I already have done research and the only other way I have found is to put myLocation variable outside of the function and only change the value inside the function, but the xcode starts to complain that the class doesn't have an initializer and I don't know what to do.

Sorry if I made any stupid mistakes as I have just started to learn code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can add user location annotation outside of didupdatelocation , for this first of all you need to store lat and long of current location in userdefault and then acess it outside function , this way u will able to mange it only once

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain a little more what I need to do? As I said I'm pretty much a complete rookie in this area and don't understand much more than pure baby code talk

Comment: did it solve your issue ?

Comment: It probably will, but I will need to dig a little deeper into storing data in userdefaults, as I don't have any experience with it yet.

Comment: let me give you the exact way to achieve it wait for 2 min , i am answering your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `LocationManager didUpdate` Methods **:**

```
//MARK: LocationManager Delegates Methods
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //Get Current Location
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        //Save current lat long
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, forKey: "LAT")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userLocation.coordinate.longitude, forKey: "LON")
        UserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
```

And then create a function and which gets called from viewWillAppear Method :

```
     func createPin(){

            //Access user Location LAT & LON from User Defaults
            let coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "LAT") as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "LON") as! CLLocationDegrees)
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        region.center = coordinate
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

//Also now you have coordintes know for USER Location you can add annotation too

    //Rest do your stuff 
    }
```

Feel free to comment if any further issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this will do it. Couldn't have done it without your help!